# Shortcut keys in c# windows application

Tags: c#

I  want to have shortcut keys like F1 for operatiosn like save,new,view in c# windows application.How can i do this?

Comment: check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171538.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial may be of some help to you: [Home & Learn: Menu Shortcuts in C# .NET](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s4p3.html), it explains how to assign shortcuts to menu items.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `KeyPreview=true` property of Form and handle `KeyDown` event or override the `ProcessCmdKey()` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `MenuStrip`, simply set the `ShortcutKeys` property for any menu item and its `Click` event will be raised when the appropriate keys are pressed.

Alternatively, if you don't have a menu or something, set your form's `KeyPreview` property to `true` and handle the `KeyDown` event:

```
public void Form1_KeyDown(KeyEventArgs e) {
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.F1) { // For example
        // Do something
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```